# Assistance to Bulkify this class processing custom objects

Tags: apex, map, bulkification, governorlimits

My org uses custom revenue schedule objects created via triggers and classes running off of the Opportunities. It is very complex (beyond my scope for updating in any reasonable time)  - it uses a delete  and re insert every time the revenue calculation is updated.
We are implementing a rebate process (percentage off) for certain Ops and I am implementing the rebate process like this:

1. Rebate_schedule__c object with dates and the rebate % so rebates can be added for appropriate months for each Op
2. Trigger on the custom revenue schedule objects to call a class to apply the discount.

Below are my trigger and class.
I can see that it does not look efficient - while only Revenue_schedule__c on Ops that have rebates will be called b/c of the trigger, the query is in the FOR loop. 
I do not know how to do this in a way robust to bulk updates, since every Revenue_schedule__c needs to check for an existing Rebate_schedule__c on that Op for that same month.

How do I make the class bulk capable by moving the query out of the for loop while still finding the correct rebate %, matched by OpId and Month (if it even exists)

Thanks!

Trigger:

```
trigger CallOpportunityRebateApplicationFrmRevSched on Revenue_Schedule__c (after insert) {

    set <id> RevsToHandle = new SET <id>();
    List <Revenue_Schedule__c> RevScheds = [select id, Opportunity__r.HasRebateSchedule__c
                      from Revenue_Schedule__c
                      where Opportunity__r.HasRebateSchedule__c > 0
                      AND id IN: Trigger.new];


    For (Revenue_schedule__c RR:RevScheds){
        RevsToHandle.add(RR.id);
    }

    if(RevsToHandle!=NULL){
        OpportunityRebateHandlerforRevSched.ApplyRebateMethod(RevsToHandle);
    }

}
```

Class (Nversion  of class - still catching ALL MONTHS are being cut and not just matched by month of Rev_schedule to month of rebate_schedule)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please [edit] your post to make clear your specific, answerable question.

Comment: Updated with explicit question

Comment: I am for now changing the model to work where the rebate schedule has one month instead of a date range. This 

way I could figure out how to bulkify using MAP methods b/c I could use a formula field on all objects 

concatenating OpportunityId and Month to make an easy key.

If anyone can figure out how to work this where the rebate object has a date range - a start and end date 

rather than a date value, I would like to see how you would do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am for now changing the model to work where the rebate schedule has one month instead of a date range. This way I could figure out how to bulkify using MAP methods b/c I could use a formula field on all objects concatenating OpportunityId and Month to make an easy key.

If anyone can figure out how to work this where the rebate object has a date range - a start and end date rather than a date value, I would like to see how you would do it.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to refactor your code eliminating extra SOQL queries and using Map.

**Trigger**

Since you are querying `Revenue_Schedule__c` records so better to include `Amount__c`, `Month__c`, `Opportunity__c` and put results into a map and pass that into Handler method.

```
trigger CallOpportunityRebateApplicationFrmRevSched on Revenue_Schedule__c (after insert) 
{
    Map<Id,Revenue_Schedule__c> RevSchedMap = 
                      new Map<Id,Revenue_Schedule__c>(
                      [SELECT id, Amount__c, Month__c, Opportunity__c, Opportunity__r.HasRebateSchedule__c
                      FROM Revenue_Schedule__c
                      WHERE Opportunity__r.HasRebateSchedule__c > 0
                      AND id IN: Trigger.new]
                      ); 

    if(RevSchedMap.keySet().size()>0){
        OpportunityRebateHandlerforRevSched.ApplyRebateMethod(RevSchedMap);
    }
}
```

**Trigger Handler**

Given necessary inline comments

```
public class OpportunityRebateHandlerforRevSched 
{
    static public void ApplyRebateMethod (Map<Id,Revenue_Schedule__c> RevsToHandle)
    {
        Set<Date> monthValues = new Set<Date>(); //this will hold month dates
        Map<Id, Id> revsFedOpptyMap = new Map<Id, Id>(); //holds Revenue_Schedule__c Id and OpportunityId

        //prepare list of month dates and revsFedOpptyMap
        for(Revenue_Schedule__c rsObj: RevsToHandle.values())
        {
            monthValues.add(rsObj.Month__c);
            revsFedOpptyMap.put(rsObj.Id, rsObj.Opportunity__c);
        }

        List <Revenue_Schedule__c> RSStoCUT = new List <Revenue_Schedule__c>();

        //retrieve MaxRebate based on OpportunityIds
        List<AggregateResult> results = [SELECT Opportunity__c, MAX (Rebate_factor__c) MaxRebate    
                                            FROM Rebate_schedule__c 
                                            WHERE Opportunity__c =: revsFedOpptyMap.values() 
                                            AND Rebate_Start_Date__c <=: monthValues
                                            AND Rebate_End_Date__c >=: monthValues
                                            GROUP BY Opportunity__c
                                   ]; 

        //prepare a map which will hold OpportunityId and MaxRebate
        Map<Id, Decimal> opptyRebateMap = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
        for(AggregateResult agg : results)
        {
            opptyRebateMap.put((Id)agg.get('Opportunity__c'),(Decimal) agg.get('MaxRebate'));
        }

        //now compare with Opportunity values and prepare a list of records to be updated   
        for(Revenue_Schedule__c rsObj: RevsToHandle.values())
        {
            if(opptyRebateMap.containsKey(rsObj.Opportunity__c))
            {
                Decimal RebateFactor = opptyRebateMap.get(rsObj.Opportunity__c);
                if(RebateFactor !=null)
                {
                    rsObj.Amount__c = (rsObj.Amount__c-(rsObj.Amount__c*RebateFactor));
                    RSStoCUT.add(rsObj);
                }
            }
        }
        update RSStoCUT;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - there are a couple variables it is not finding - is "revsFed"  supposed to be "RevsToHandle" ?

Comment: and needed to switch  for(AggregateResult agg : aggResult) to  for(AggregateResult agg : results) - just checking, thanks

Comment: Odd error - i am getting Unexpected Token for the { in the line -  if(opptyRebateMap.containsKey(rsObj.Opportunity__c)
            {

Comment: I have written a logic in textpad, since I dont have those objects I am not able to compile. But the logic I have tried to show, it will work

Comment: gotcha, thanks. Made one update,  RSStoCUT.add(RSSA); became  RSStoCUT.add(rsObj);

Comment: put proper debug statement to check everything is working as expected

Comment: I used this also as a guide to apply to another parallel revenue scheduling object and both classes are working handling opportunities with large numbers of revenue schedules and line items and rebates!

Comment: This is applying the rebate to all items, and not just where the month of the rebate_schedule__c maps to the month/date of the Revenue_Schedule__c

Comment: Then you need to take the month in that condition when you are looping

Comment: So  if(opptyRebateMap.containsKey(rsObj.Opportunity__c)){ needs to be followed by a if for a contains same month? but where in which map do i compare?

Comment: no, in the SOQL query, you need to add month column for grouping which is currently group by Opportunity, then you can easily perform month based update

Comment: Create a formula field which will display the month and add that formula field in the grouping, or trying grouping with monthValues, it will work

Comment: I am not sure how to group by Opp and Month and compare on the maps. I can make a formulafield for the revenue obj b/c it is 1 month but the rebate schedule is over a range of dates.

Comment: why are we sending a map in the  trigger and not just a set/list of the obj?

Comment: I have added formula fields making unique Opportunity and Month strings on all the objects - will have to convert to making one rebate per month rather than one with start and end dates and will try to build the linked map calculation on this since other way seems impossible

Comment: thats a good option, then you will get monthwise data

Answer (score 0):

This is rough, but I hope you can get the jist of what I'm doing.. There may be compile errors because I eyeballed it but you should be figure out the direction that I was going

But essentally my goal here was to try and figure out all the data that is required and then  using Maps retrieve the data

```
public class OpportunityRebateHandlerforRevSched 
{
    static public void ApplyRebateMethod (Set<ID> revsToHandle)
    {
        Map<ID, Revenue_Schedule__c> revOpptys = new Map<ID, Revenue_Schedule__c>();

        for(Revenue_Schedule__c rev : [SELECT id, Amount__c, Month__c, Opportunity__c FROM Revenue_Schedule__c WHERE ID IN: revsToHandle]])
        {
            revOpptys.put(rev.Opportunity__c, rev);
        }

        List<AggregateResult> aggResult = [select ID, Opportunity__c, Rebate_Start_Date__c, Rebate_End_Date__c,  MAX (Rebate_factor__c) MaxRebate FROM 
        Rebate_schedule__c where Opportunity__c =: revOpptyIDS.keySet() GROUP BY Opportunity__c];

        for(ID rssaID : revOpptys.keySet())
        {
            for(AggregateResult agg : aggResult)
            {
                if(aggResult.get('Opportunity__c') == rssaID && agg.Rebate_Start_Date__c <= revOpptys.get('Opportunity__c').Month__c && 
                    agg.Rebate_End_Date__c >=: revOpptys.get('Opportunity__c').Month__c)
                {
                    revOpptys.get(rssaID).Amount__c = (revOpptys.get(rssaID).Amount__c - (revOpptys.get(rssaID).Amount__c * (Decimal) agg.get('MaxRebate');   
                }
            }
        }

        update revOpptys.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I will try to work on this. Maps are my weakest skill in apex.

Comment: I think I see where going - some compile issues - but I think the concept - I will post my trial above

Comment: Not quite sure how MAP is mapping the Revenue_schedule__c to Rebate Schedule since it must match OPPORTUNITY and the MONTH